# Memorability of words?

Tags: psycholinguistics

I'm asking this here as I'm not seeing a psycho-linguistic group, and I think that is what I'm looking at.
I'm hoping there is some degree of crossover.

Is there a specific word or phrase used that means how memorable a word/phrase is?
Are there any resources that list words and phrases with such scores, or a way I could (even roughly) calculate a measure for memorability?

At present, the best I can come up with is Frequency.
A key component of memory is exposure.  Frequency of usage could, with a little shaving and dressing, be used to represent possible exposure.  I can find resources for frequency of words and phrases.
I could adjust this by length, or even cobble a kind of complexity measure based on syllables.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Anemone has more mnemonicity than amnesty does.

Comment: That's good to know.  Thank you.  What about the other 300K+ english words? :D  Is it safe to assume that no one here knows of any memorability metrics or a way to estimate such ?

Comment: There is a proposal in SPE (**The Sound Pattern of English**) about how the pronunciations of morphemes are stored in memory -- it's the markedness theory of chapter 9.  It's never been interpreted as an actual psychological hypothesis, so far as I know, it's awfully complicated, and nobody believes it, so far as I know.  Best I can do.

Comment: Well, a PsyLing has various features, including imageability.  It seems the more likely a word is to be imagined, the better the recall.  It seems to have a strong correlation with Frequency/exposure too.  But I was hoping there was a way to calculate likely memorability based on "something".  Looks like I'll just have to fudge it with Frequency as a rough representation :(  At least I can use that for bi/tri/quad-grams etc.

Comment: @alexandergill Did you ever figure this out?